# how can i get leaveTypeList from this json object from json array and how to add that list to a spinner

Tags: java, android

how can i get `leaveTypeList` from this json object from json array

```
 {
   "id": "571ded555a9d4d45896f1131",
   "orgId": "55f7cc58e4b05248134d6fe6",
   "designationList": [
      "Jr. Software Engineer",
      "SQL Administrator",
      "Sr. UX Designer",
      "Team Lead",
      "Technical Lead",
      "Jr.Quality Analyst",
      "Finance & Admin",
      "Employee"
   ],
   "streamList": [
      "Java",
      "Android",
      ".NET"
   ],
   "taskTypeList": [
      "S",
      "M",
      "L",
      "XL"
   ],
   "taskPriorityList": [
      "High",
      "Medium",
      "Low"
   ],
   "leaveTypeList": [
      "Casual Leave",
      "Sick Leave",
      "Special Sick Leave",
      "Compensatory Leave",
      "Unplanned Leave",
      "Maternity Leave",
      "Paternity Leave",
      "Work From Home"
   ],
   "eventTypeList": [
      "Holiday",
      "Meeting"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
    JSONArray leaveTypeList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("leaveTypeList");
    for (int i=0; i< leaveTypeList.length(); i++) {
        String type = leaveTypeList.getString(i);
        System.out.println(type);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this codes. Hope it will work

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONArray leaveTypeList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("leaveTypeList");

for (int i = 0; leaveTypeList.length(); i++) {
   leaveTypeList.getString(i);  
}
```